# UICollectionView: change the sizeForItemAtIndexPath from within custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

A very basic question about model-view-controller (MVC).

I have a custom UICollectionView filled with custom `UICollectionViewCells`. The collection view defines the size of the cells within the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method, `collectionView: sizeForItemAtIndexPath`. Meanwhile, subviews are added and removed via the custom collection cell view controller.

My question: when adding or removing subviews from the cell's view controller, how do I also tell the collection view controller to change the height?

I do understand delegate and data source concepts, but figure that the cell is it's own delegate, so how does the message ('change the height to...') get passed from the cell to the collection view controller when subviews are added/removed?

Comment: I think you are adding or removing subviews in the datasource function >cellForItemAtIndexPath there you can manually change the cell frame and it will work

Comment: @Muhammad. I am adding and removing subviews that are within the cells from within the cell controller. I want each cell to behave independently of each other. I then want to change the height of a specific cell from within the collection controller.

Comment: I mean to say that where you are adding or removing subviews there you can update frame of that particular cell using cell.frame

Comment: @Muhammad - I see. Good idea! But is it possible to only change the size and not the whole CGRect of self.frame for the cell? I want to stick with the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout. If I use .frame, it seems to want a CGRect with x and y values, which I guess will break both autolayout and the collection view flow layout? Or am I misunderstanding it again.

Comment: Yes you can do this by using this code
CGRect cellFrame=cell.frame;  cellFrame.size.height=100;
    cell.frame=cellFrame;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using notification center,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AddedSubViewToCell" object:self];
```

and in collection view controller's viewDidLoad,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addedSubViewToCell:) name:@"AddedSubViewToCell" object:nil];
```

and then implement the selector

```
- (void)addedSubViewToCell:(NSNotification:)notificationObject
{
     //change frame of collection view
     //don't forget to remove observer
}
```

For Detailed Explanation regarding `NSNotificationCenter`, See this [Tutorial](http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/using-nsnotificationcenter-with-example/)

Hope this helps.
Thanks

Comment: Cool! That works, and opens up a whole world of possibilities to explore. I found this [super basic code explanation of Notification Center](http://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/), and this slightly more detailed explanation of how to [pass parameters between VCs with Notification Center](http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/nsnotifications-with-userinfo-in-swift/).

Comment: Good to hear that,.. Thanks @  DrWhat