# Create IBAction of UIButton in one view controller and influence the action in another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, ibaction

I am planning to create two UIViewController. Basically, there are some buttons in one of the two view controllers. When I press one of these buttons, I want to trigger some action in another view controller. Are there some ways to make it possible?

Comment: Use delegate methods.

Comment: In the addTarget method, put the other viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

There are so three possible ways to do that,

Using `NSNotificationCenter`, Using `Delegates` and the last one is using `Blocks`, The first option is easy to learn.

1. Add the observer in to FirstViewController
2. Post notification in SecondViewController (when user clicks the button)

For reference follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28109897/3733561)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a delegate for that.

For example, you may have this ViewControllers.

```
//FirstViewController.h

@protocol ProtocolName <NSObject>

  - (void)doSomething;

@end

@interface FirstViewController

 @property (nonatomic, strong) id<ProtocolName> delegate;

 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

 - (IBAction)action:(id)sender;

@end
```

Here we need a protocol, who defines one or more methods to be implemented in any Object who implement this protocol. And also we need a delegate, that is an object who implements this protocol (in this case called "ProtocolName", but you can name it as you wish).

And then a second ViewController

```
//SecondViewController.h
#import "FirstViewController.h" //Need this to reference protocol

@interface SecondViewController <ProtocolName>

@end
```

With  we are saying that SecondViewController will implement ProtocolName protocol, so in his .m file we need to do this.

```
//SecondViewController.m

- (void)doSomething{
  //Do something
}
```

And here comes the magic.

Let's say that when you tap the button in FirstViewController it triggers the doSomething method in SecondViewController. So, you need to do something like this.

```
//FirstViewController.m

//...
SecondViewController secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
this.delegate = secondVC; //DON'T FORGET THIS
//...

- (IBAction)action:(id)sender{ 
 [this.delegate doSomething];
}
```

And this is the delegate pattern.